# error: invalid type argument of unary '*'

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I don't understand these errors can someone explain?

error: invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'double')
error: invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'double')
error: invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'double')

```
    double getMedian(double *array, int *hours){
    if (*hours <= 0) return 0;
    if (*hours % 2) return (float)*array[(*hours + 1) / 2];
    else{int pos = *hours / 2;
    return (float)(*array[pos] + *array[pos + 1]) / 2;}}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are already dereferencing `array` with the `[]` operator. What you want is:

```
double getMedian(double *array, int *hours){
if (*hours <= 0) return 0;
if (*hours % 2) return (float)array[(*hours + 1) / 2];
else{int pos = *hours / 2;
return (float)(array[pos] + array[pos + 1]) / 2;}}
```

Note that writing `x[y]` is shorthand for `*(x + (y))`. In your code, you have essentially have the equivalent of `**array`.

Answer (score 2):

When you use the [] operator on the arrays or pointers, you don't have to dereference them again to get the value.
you could just say,

```
if (*hours % 2) return (float)array[(*hours + 1) / 2];
```

and

```
return (float)(array[pos] + (array[pos + 1]) / 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

`*array[(*hours + 1) / 2];` so `array` is an array of doubles. You treating it as a 2D array because you try to dereference once via `*` and one via `[]`.

Also, I'd add some `()` to all of that to make it a bit clearer without having to memorise the order of operations.